# Address of + zero index, then dereference, undefined behavior in C in some circumstances or always?

Tags: c, gcc, undefined-behavior

Is the following undefined behaviour in C? If so, why is it undefined behaviour? Is it undefined in all of the standards, or only some?

```
int test(char *p)
{
    int i = 0;
    char *p2;

    p2 = *(&p + i);
}
```

With GCC p2 seems to be as expected simply the same as p, given that i is 0.

I am aware that it really makes no sense to perform this statement, but I find it interesting nonetheless.

Just to be clear, I'm not looking for a general answer as to what undefined behaviour is. I think there are several nice tutorials and papers on the topic, e.g. http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/papers/ub:apsys12.pdf and http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html

Comment: There's no undefined behaviour; the compiler can optimize `i` out of the function as written.  Indeed, with the code shown, the whole function is a no-op, but assuming `p2` were really used, or returned, or something, then what's shown would all be OK (no undefined behaviour).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior is well defined. You are taking the address of a pointer. With i = 0, you don't modify the address. But if i was 1, you would increment the address of the pointer by the bus width 4 or 8 bytes. If p was from an array of pointers that would be ok. If not, you would crash if you tried to read from p2.

Comment: "*But if i was 1 ...*" it would necessarily crash the program, but it definitly would invoke undefined behaviour. However: 1+